# Not able to create live folders after Lumia Denim Update on Lumia 520

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520, lumia-denim-update

I updated my Lumia 520 to the latest Lumia Denim firmware yesterday, and now I am not able to create live folders. I have dragged one app over another but it did not work.

That is how we create them right?

Comment: Probably you've just updated to Lumia Cyan. Try searching for an update, and you'll find Lumia Denim. Good luck mate

Comment: The Denim update doesn't introduce folders by itself, what "OS version" is shown in Settings > About ?

Comment: Is it definitely Lumia Denim? My phone also showed Denim for a few days (even though it's still on Black), then it switched back to showing the correct Lumia version.

Comment: Go to settings -> Extras + info . As all say check whether its in denim and post your build number here. So that it will be easy to check ..

Comment: Check what build number is shown in your lumia and update us, so that it will be easy for all to resolve your issue..

Answer (score 1):

Folders are not a feature of the Lumia Denim firmware but are introduced with the **Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1**. Check if your OS version matches on of these:

> Windows Phone 8.1 Update
>   OS version: 8.10.14141.167, 8.10.14147.180, 8.10.14157.200, 8.10.14176.243, 8.10.14192.280, 8.10.14203.206, 8.10.14219.341, or 8.10.14226.359

[Windows Phone 8 update history](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/windows-phone-8-update-history)